# How to implement options (hop-by-hop) within an IP header, specifically IPv6?

Tags: network-programming, udp, stack, ipv6

I am quite new to network programming in general and so far have done a few applications using UDP.

1.) Who actually adds a header to a datagram, the operating system TCP/IP stack?

2.) If I want to affect what is in the IPv6 header using extensions, what are the steps? Does this occur in my UDP application? Do I need to use raw sockets?

I nonchalantly can tell my datagram it's destination IP address & port and it ends up in the header, but I am naive and do not understand the process of how that occurs.

I tried researching this, but cannot find much and believe maybe I don't know how to ask my question properly.

Answer (score 1):

For the most common use cases the operating system provides functionality to create and parse the IP packet. If you want to do "special" things like adding extra extension headers you often need to do so everything manually.

Operating systems often also require administrator/root access to do so to prevent ordinary users from doing things they're not supposed to.

Comment: I have administrator/root privileges. In regards to adding a hop-by-hop extension header, do I need raw sockets or no? Do I need a library? I'm mainly looking for implementation ideas.

Comment: If your operating system doesn't provide an API for what you want then you'll need raw sockets. I would advise you to use a library for parsing and creating raw packets because writing your own IP stack is error prone.